# Maven runs test but it does not display results

Tags: java, maven, junit

I've just started working with maven and I can't figure out how to solve the problem I have. It seems to my java file is compiled and test starts but no result shows up.

Demo.java:

```
package tutorial2;

public class Demo {

public boolean getBool(){
    return false;
}
```

}

TestDemo.java:

```
package tutorial2;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestDemo {

@Test
public void shouldBe(){
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    assertTrue(demo.getBool());
}

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>lets.develop.withme</groupId>
  <artifactId>tutorial2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Tutorial 02</name>
  <description>My second tutorial</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

</project
```

I'm getting this on console:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Tutorial 02 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ tutorial2 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ tutorial2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ tutorial2 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tutorial2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ tutorial2 ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/adam/workspaceJavaEE/tutorial2/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running tutorial2.TestDemo
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.943 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-14T00:34:25+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Solved:

I solved problem by myself. Dependency in xml file was not configured properly. Version of junit dependency was wrong so It could't be run by maven.

### Advise:

You should always add dependencies by "Insert Dependency" menu. It can be displayed by using shortcut "crtl"+"space" when your cursor is between `<dependency>` and `</dependency>` in your xml file. When you in "Select Dependency" menu enter "junit" in "Enter..." textbox and choose your version of junit. After clicking "ok" your dependency will be automatically added. This helps avoid problem with incorrect version typed manually.

Comment: Uhhh no. It's not running your test: `Tests run: 0`

Comment: It's often better here to write your own solution as an answer to your own question (totally allowed) instead of editing it into the question. Glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Surefire (the plugin that runs during `mvn test`) looks for classes in `target/test-classes` (which are compiled from `src/test/java` and maybe other places) that end in `Test`. Your class name is `TestDemo`, which doesn't end in `Test`, and won't be run. Either rename it to `DemoTest` (preferable), or manually configure Surefire in `<plugins>` (the approach when you're using a framework with alternate naming conventions, such as Spock's `*Spec`).

Answer (score 0):

According to maven documentation avalible [on](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html):

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test
>   classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> "/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that start with "Test". "/*Test.java" - includes all of
>   its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
>   "/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that end with "TestCase".